# PyCharm: Как отобразить все столбцы данных в окне "Выполнить"

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

При загрузке таблицы (Excel),  PyCharm выводит не все колонки. А нужны все. Как можно это исправить?

```
import pandas as pd

path = 'https://spimex.com/upload/reports/oil_xls/oil_xls_20200901162000.xls?r=1149'

def editt_data (path):
    data = pd.read_excel(path, skiprows= 7)
    data_no_columns = data.drop(data.columns[[0,3,5,7,9]], axis='columns')
    data_no_columns.set_axis(['Код','Нефтепродукт','Кол-во, т','Динамика, руб/т','Min цена, руб/т','Max цена, руб/т','Рыночная цена, руб/т','Лучшее предложение','Лучший спрос', 'Кол-во  сделок'], axis='columns', inplace=True)

    return data_no_columns

print(editt_data(path))
```

```
                  Код  ... Кол-во  сделок
0         A100NBK025A  ...              -
1         A100STI060F  ...              1
2         A100UFM060F  ...              -
3         A101PDK065F  ...              -
4         A106PDK065F  ...              -
..                ...  ...            ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте глобальные настройки Pandas:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
```